# Fusing EMR Operators not working in Airflow

Tags: airflow, amazon-emr

I am trying to fuse `EmrAddStepsOperator` and `EmrStepSensor` using a custom Operator in Airflow and inheriting both `EmrAddStepsOperator` and `EmrStepSensor` , but getting `missing keyword` exception.

How can I fuse these two Operators ?

Thanks

The definition used for the same is

```
class EMRAddStepToCluster(EmrAddStepsOperator, EmrStepSensor):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs["step_id"] = None
        super(EMRAddStepToCluster, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def execute(self, context):
        self.step_id = super(EmrAddStepsOperator, self).execute(context)
        super(EmrStepSensor, self).execute(context)
```

I am using this operator in the following manner:

```
create_job_flow = EmrCreateJobFlowOperator(
        task_id="create_job_flow",
        job_flow_overrides=JOB_FLOW_OVERRIDES,
    )

my_emr_job = EMRAddStepToCluster(
        task_id="hive_config_creation",
        job_flow_id="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull('create_job_flow', key='return_value') }}",
        steps=HIVE_CONFIG_CREATION
    )
```

When trying to create a DAG using this definition, I am getting the following exception:

```
[2023-06-22T09:48:30.242+0000] {{logging_mixin.py:137}} INFO - [2023-06-22T09:48:30.241+0000] {{dagbag.py:342}} ERROR - Failed to import: /usr/local/airflow/dags/my_workflow_example.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/models/dagbag.py", line 338, in parse
    loader.exec_module(new_module)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/local/airflow/dags/my_workflow_example.py", line 617, in <module>
    hive_config_creation = EMRAddStepToCluster(
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/models/baseoperator.py", line 408, in apply_defaults
    result = func(self, **kwargs, default_args=default_args)
  File "/usr/local/airflow/dags/my_workflow_example.py", line 27, in __init__
    super(EMRAddStepToCluster, self).__init__(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/models/baseoperator.py", line 408, in apply_defaults
    result = func(self, **kwargs, default_args=default_args)
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/operators/emr.py", line 74, in __init__
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/models/baseoperator.py", line 391, in apply_defaults
    raise AirflowException(f"missing keyword argument {missing_args.pop()!r}")
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: missing keyword argument 'job_flow_id'
```

Since I was getting this exception, I tried passing `job_flow_id` explicitly and used the following declaration:

```
class EMRAddStepToCluster(EmrAddStepsOperator, EmrStepSensor):

    def __init__(self, job_flow_id **kwargs):
        kwargs["step_id"] = None
        kwargs["job_flow_id"] = job_flow_id
        super(EMRAddStepToCluster, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def execute(self, context):
        self.step_id = super(EmrAddStepsOperator, self).execute(context)
        super(EmrStepSensor, self).execute(context)
```

But still getting the same exception.

Comment: Was not able to find a way to do this. Had to fall back to create a python function to execute both `EmrAddStepsOperator` and  `EmrStepSensor` one after another and use a `PythonOperator` to execute this function.